# Solving differential forms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential-forms

I am trying to solve this equation:
[image: DE]

$dz = \frac{x^2+z-y^2}{x} dx + \frac{y^2+xy-z}{x} dy$

With the following form:

$dq_3 = B_1 dq_1 + B_2 dq_2$

condition (taking dq1.dq2=dq2.dq1)is:

$\frac{\partial B_1}{\partial q_2} + \frac{\partial B_1}{\partial q_3} B_2 = \frac{\partial B_2}{\partial q_1} + \frac{\partial B_2}{\partial q_3} B_1$.

RHS = $\frac{-x^2}{x^2}=-1$ which is true

LHS= $\frac{-2y}{x} + \frac{y^2+xy-z}{x^2} = \frac{y^2-xy-z}{x^2}$ this should be -1!

the solution is: $z = x^2-xy+y^2$

Question:

- What is wrong with my calculations?

note: This is used to prove holonomic constraints for [Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) and I think it isn't relevant to include that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I checked your solution. It has no error!

Comment: @Nosrati ,but the equation should be solvable and the condition holds? OR Am I missing something?

Comment: $z = x^2-xy+y^2$ satisfies the equation.

Comment: And it has no singularties, so this should be true $\frac{\partial B_1}{\partial q_2} + \frac{\partial B_1}{\partial q_3} B_2 = \frac{\partial B_2}{\partial q_1} + \frac{\partial B_2}{\partial q_3} B_1$, but how can I proceed when the condition is dependent on variables. How to check integrability?

Comment: Your approach only works if there are no $z$'s appearing in the $dx$ and $dy$ terms. Interestingly, the original $1$-form (or differential) is definitely *not* exact. Indeed, there's not even an integrating factor (a necessary condition is that $d\omega\wedge\omega = 0$ if $\omega$ is the $1$-form, and this fails).

Comment: Kindly correct me. I think that integrability means there exist a $z= \int dz$. and it has a solution! and the condition kind of work. I am new to exterior derivative.